# How to use ng-href instead of ng-click to make a make <a> as hyperlink and route to different state in angular 2.2?

Tags: javascript, html, angular, scope, routes

Path: html->search.js->app.src.js

HTML Code:

NEWS1

SEARCH.JS CODE:

```
$scope.gotoDetail = function(type, id, item){
    if(type === 'PROJECT'){
        $state.go('app.project.detail', ({projectId: id}));
    } else if(type === 'JOB'){
        $state.go('app.job.detail', ({jobId: id}));
    } else if(type === 'COMMENT'){
        var jobId = _.find(item.context, {'key':'entityId'}).value;
        $state.go('app.job.detail', ({jobId: jobId, tab: 'discussion'}));
    } else if(type === 'PRODUCT'){
        $state.go('app.product.detail', ({productId: id}));
    } else if(type === 'COMPONENT'){
        $state.go('app.component.detail', ({componentId: id}));
    } else if(type === 'CUSTOMER'){
        $state.go('app.customer.detail', ({customerId: id}));
    }
}
```

APP.SRC.JS CODE:

```
    .state('app.project.add', {
      url: '/add' + filters['projectsAdd'],
      templateUrl: 'tpl/project/project.add.html',
      resolve: load([
        'js/controllers/project/project.add.js',
        'js/controllers/project/project.trial.add.js',
        'js/controllers/project/project.samples.sync.dialog.js',
        'ngBootbox',
        'ang-drag-drop',
        'angularMoment'
      ]),
      params: {
        mode: 'add',
      },
    })
```

I want to make NEW1 as a hyperlink. I mean when someone does a left click on it then the page should reload and when someone does right click it should show the options like open a new tab, open a new window, ... just link a link.

Current Behaviour:
 I cant it is not like a hyperlink. If someone click on "NEWS1" it will reload in the same page

Expected:
Hello should act like a hyper link.

I tried using ng-href instead of ng-click but no luck.

Comment: HTML Code: <a ng-click = "gotoDetail(result.entityType, result.id, result)" class="font-bold">NEWS1</a>

Comment: you are not using Angular :(

Comment: I am using ng-click which is angular js